# Optimal way to store data in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to store this information and retrieve it quickly (potentially without much processing).

Example:

```
'americanexpress'=>{maxchar=>30,special_char=>false,numbers=>true,capital=>true},
'discover'=>{maxchar=>29,special_char=>true,numbers=>true,capital=>false}
```

I want to be able to access say [americanexpress] or [discover] separately and its associated data.

I thought `arrays` might work (but single dim. didnt seem too work well), then i thought `dictionary`, but that didnt seem right either.

Anyone give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: Why `dictionary` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Because you are using key/value pairs, dictionaries are probably unavoidable. Could you explain more why dictionary doesn't seem right?

Could you also explain how fast you prefer to store and retrieve the data, and if it is to disk or to a variable?

Comment: I do not understand why this question is being downvoted. It is legitimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = { 
    'americanexpress': { 
        'maxchar': 30, 
        'special_char': False, 
        'numbers': True, 
        'capital': True 
    }, 
    'discover': { 
        'maxchar': 29, 
        'special_char': True, 
        'numbers': True, 
        'capital': False 
    } 
} 

# Yes, it works 
assert d['americanexpress']['maxchar'] == 30 
assert d['discover']['capital'] is False
```

Please note that even if there are ways have a simpler syntax for the same purpose (like using classes) it's usually just a [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) so the performance is not improved.

You can use lists but then you lose named items, or you can use individual variables like `americanexpress_maxchar` but this doesn't seem to be required.